# filter a range using a hash kind of list

Tags: prolog

I am c++ guy and i am completely new to prolog.
I am using sicstus prolog.

i came across a need as below:

lets say i have a variable

```
A={0,1,2,3}
B={-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5}
```

and i have hash kind of thing like

```
0-{3}
1-{4}
```

now i need to filter the values of A and B using this hash so that after the operation:

```
A={0,1}
B={3,4}
```

logic is values  from A will be matched with keys of the hash

if the key exists then check for the value.if the value exists in B then the value in A remains.
otherwise value should be deleted.
in the same way it should be done for B with the values in the hash shoul dbe searched in A and if not present then it should be deleted in B.
means the exactly opposite way for B.

Could anybody please help?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use lists to hold the keys and values of A and B, and a list of `Key-Value` pairs to hold your hashmap. That way you can use builtin helper predicates `include/3` and `memberchk/2` to suit your needs.

Then you can write a procedure that filters the items of A and B:

```
filter(A, B, Hash, FA, FB):-
  include(filterkey(B, Hash), A, FA),
  include(filtervalue(A, Hash), B, FB).

filterkey(B, Hash, Item):-
  memberchk(Item-Value, Hash),
  memberchk(Value, B).

filtervalue(A, Hash, Value):-
  memberchk(Item-Value, Hash),
  memberchk(Item, A).
```

Say if you have

```
A=[0,1,2,3]
B=[-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5]
Hash=[0-3, 1-4]
```

then:

```
?- A=[0,1,2,3], B=[-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5], Hash=[0-3, 1-4], filter(A, B,Hash, FA, FB).
Hash = [0-3, 1-4],
FA = [0, 1],
FB = [3, 4].
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't have Sicstus available to test, and then I could be completely out-of-track, but you are handling a *very* peculiar kind of variables. Consider

```
?- write_canonical({1,2,3,4}).
{}(','(1,','(2,','(3,4))))

?- {1,2,3,4}={A}.
A = (1, 2, 3, 4).
```

Braces are really just a peculiar name for a tuple, and AFAIK are used just as syntactic device to introduce readable data in a DSL (Domain Specific Language), like for instance *constraints* in library([clpqr](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.8%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/clpqr.html%27%29%29)).

What I mean is that or

- you are using the *wrong* representation for the task (gusbro addressed this problem, +1)
- you are searching for a clp constraint extension (filtering?) not available in Sicstus. But then the question should be reformulated in better terms.

Anyway you could adapt gusbro' answer *without changing* your program if you add, for instance,

```
member_set(E, {','(E,_)}).
member_set(E, {','(_,T)}) :- member_set(E, {T}).
member_set(E, {E}).
```

to replace memberchk. include/3 must be rewritten also, but it's not so easy.
Otherwise, a conversion predicate

```
set_list({','(A,B)}, [A|R]) :- set_list({B}, R), !.
set_list({E}, [E]).
set_list({}, []).
```

could be handy:

```
?- set_list(S,[1,2,3]).
S = {1, 2, 3}.

?- set_list({1,2,3},L).
L = [1, 2, 3].
```